# How can I get the started user inside Jenkins Job even in downstream project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins job shell, I want to get the user who starts the build in the shell, how can I do it ?

The [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) works well if this job was started by user, while it is triggered by others like upstream job, it doesn't work. The value like `$BUILD_USER` is empty.

see comments from author "Gavriil" in that page

> This is not a bug. Build user could be identified only in case if
>   build was started by user. If build was triggered by other cause, f.e.
>   by timer or by end of upstream job

Though in the job console, actually I can see the user information

```
Started by upstream project "arctifact2slave" build number 16
originally caused by: 
Started by upstream project "create-vm" build number 5
originally caused by: 
Started by user larrycai
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are exactly trying to achieve but the way I understand it, you could do the following.

- Add a String parameter to your root job. Affect it the BUILD_USER variable value. ie:`${BUILD_USER}`
- Then just pass the Current Build Parameters in the 'Post-build Actions -> Trigger parameterized build on other projects' section.

The subsequent job will be able to read the variable.

Comment: Thx. Step 1: I want the BUILD_USER can be set automatically, if using string parameter, people need to fill the information. This is done by the plugin I mentioned.

Comment: Step 2 is ok, which I used now, and I want to see whether there is better way for this.

Comment: Doesn't your plugin already give access to the username using BUILD_USER variable ? What I'm suggesting is adding a String Parameter in the root job with **${BUILD_USER}** (BUILD_USER's value) as **Default Value**. This way you won't need to fill the username manually. Although if you trigger the job manually there will be an additional step. You'll need to click on the **Build** button after **Build now**.